# ARP protocol with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'am wondering if it's possible to implement a ARP request using Node.js and the Raw Socket module founded [here](https://npmjs.org/package/raw-socket)

Thanks in advance

Comment: With ARP do you mean: *Address Resolution Protocol*?

Comment: yes i need to implement that protocol in Node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is possible, but it won't be easy, tough.

You can use [raw-socket](https://www.npmjs.org/package/raw-socket) and check the modules that are using it to mimic behaviour, like [net-ping](https://www.npmjs.org/package/net-ping), which is no more than ICMP, a protocol at the level 3 in the OSI stack.

**EDIT:**

ARP is at the level 2 (data link layer) of the OSI model, but that doesn't matter since with raw sockets you can do it perfectly :)

Comment: It turns out the author of that package does not assure it works for layer 2 in any platform.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use arpjs on node, to send ARP requests as you wish.

Try it here:

https://github.com/skepticfx/arpjs

Comment: Its dependency pcap is no longer maintained and you cannot install it on newer node versions.

Comment: It's almost unusable because its a binding not a arp parser.